# How to create water marking effects?

Tags: teechart

Are there ways to create a water marking effect such that the bars of a chart overlap some background icon?

Thanks

Comment: Are you tring to do this by coding? Any attempts with something? Give more details!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw text directly to chart canvas using its TextOut or RotateLabel methods as in the examples on those threads:

http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1055&p=3496&hilit=custom+drawing+textout#p3496

http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10850&p=51992&hilit=textout#p51992